# Convert Json to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have working code,

```
$output=json_encode($data);
$results=json_decode($output, TRUE);

foreach ($results['results'] as $id) {
    echo $id['id'] . '<br/>';
}
```

But what i am trying to do is list not only the ID's of the JSON output but also the "subject" Associated with each ID right next or below it. not sure how to do so.

Comment: Where is this "subject" stored?  What does `var_dump($results);` show?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach ($results['results'] as $item) {
  echo 'id: '. $item['id'] . ' subject: '. $item['subject'] .'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I KNOW this is a step beyond it, but the way i am displaying this is with a form. Is there a way after this is done that on the results page i can have a Button to display that specific "Ticket"?  a click view on the right side of each line?

Comment: If I understood correctly then yes. Just add it before <br/>

Comment: i just tried to add it as a submit button but of course that didnt work. i basically have in the script an if statement from a previous page <form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ID" value="ID"/>

Comment: im guessing theres no way to put html code for a submit button inside that foreach loop? PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: echo '<input type=\"submit\" name=\"ViewTicket\" value=\"'. $item['id'] .'\"/>';   i got it but i think my format is wrong?

Comment: Updated, echo '<input type="submit" name="ViewTicket" value="'. $item['id'] .'"/>';   but of course the code wont work . i guess its looped or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo "<form action=\"former.php\" method=\"post\">";
  echo '<input type="text" name="TicketID" value="'. $item['id'] .'"/>';
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"View\" value=\"View\" />";
```

the Above is working for me BUT it wont let me view the Specific ID . it just defaults to the last ID in the array. @veNuker

Comment: just wanted to see if you have any thoughts? @veNuker

Comment: it's probably because you are using it outside foreach loop, read this http://devzone.zend.com/7/php-101-part-3-looping-the-loop/